# error with simple echo program

Tags: java, client-server, echo

I am trying to run a simple echo program, however it keeps catching an IOException, and I have no clue why!! Anyone know where I am going wrong? (BAHBAHBAH is the name of my computer).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class EchoClient {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Socket echoSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {
        echoSocket = new Socket("BAHBAHBAH", 7);
        out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    echoSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                           + "the connection to: taranis.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

 BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                               new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 String userInput;

 while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
 out.println(userInput);
 System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
 }

 out.close();
 in.close();
 stdIn.close();
 echoSocket.close();
 }
 }
```

the stack trace is as follows:

```
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at EchoClient.main(EchoClient.java:12)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.symbol.JavaClass$JavaMethod.evaluate(JavaClass.java:362)
at             edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.handleMethodCall(ExpressionEvaluator.java:92     )
at  .rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.visit(ExpressionEvaluator.java:84)
at koala.dynamicjava.tree.StaticMethodCall.acceptVisitor(StaticMethodCall.java:121)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.value(ExpressionEvaluator.java:38)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.value(ExpressionEvaluator.java:37)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.visit(StatementEvaluator.java:106)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.visit(StatementEvaluator.java:29)
at koala.dynamicjava.tree.ExpressionStatement.acceptVisitor(ExpressionStatement.java:101)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.evaluateSequence(StatementEvaluator.java:66)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.java:77)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:47)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.repl.newjvm.InterpreterJVM.interpret(InterpreterJVM.java:246)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.repl.newjvm.InterpreterJVM.interpret(InterpreterJVM.java:220)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: taranis.

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: Please try using a port above 1024 and ensuring your security software isn't blocking the connection.

Comment: @ServerMonkey But port 7 is the reserved port for echo...

Comment: In order for your program to connect, the echo server/service must be running on your system and the port must not be blocked.  It is typically for echo to be disabled by default and even the port to be blocked as it presents a possible security risk...

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem most likely in this statement:

```
    echoSocket = new Socket("BAHBAHBAH", 7);
```

Make sure that the hostname and port you are trying to connect is correct. I doubt both of them are incorrect. There are reserved porst between 0-1024 and not sure which service you are trying to connect on port 7.

Make sure some server is listening on port 7 and hostname "BAHBAHBAH". You can check this by trying to do the telnet on that host and port using the command:

```
telnet BAHBAHBAH 7
```

If it does not through any error, that means there is a service listening on that host and port.

Comment: FYI, by default telnet client is disabled on Windows 7. Good tip though, +1

Comment: @user2621169 I am not recommending the code, telnet command you can run from the command prompt to see whether you can reach to the machine and port you are trying to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a server program run and listen on the same port as well.

```
Socket serverEchoSocket;
ServerSocket echoService;

try {
   echoService = new ServerSocket(7);
   serverEchoSocket = echoService.accept();
} catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Not really, echo is service which can run on many different platforms, if enabled and not blocked by fire walls.  It's more likely that the service is disabled or blocked

Comment: this is not a proper constructor for a server socket

Comment: @user2621169 Thanks for the spot mate. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

i think a socket must be put into listening state before you get input stream....and you get outputstream when you receive a connection